# Multiple Dbcontext binding with a single interface using Ninject

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject

I have 2 Dbcontext class AdminDbContext , and AppDbContext for my web api project,both them implements IDbcontext.

My problem is Ninject is not able to resolve dependency so i get parameterless constructor error

i do not have any specific condition so contextual binding seems tough please help with this

Comment: you can always choose to bind and inject `AdminDbContext` and `AppDbContext` directly...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you can't inject IDbContext into your class as you sometimes need AdminDbContext and sometimes AppDbContext within the same class, so you can't write the Ninject binding.

In this case you can write an IDbContextFactory interface and inject that.

```
public interface IDbContextFactory
{
    IDbContext CreateAdminContext();
    IDbContext CreateAppContext();
}

public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
{
    //implementation of above interface methods to return the relevant context.
}
```

Then your class can inject that instead of the context

```
public class YourClass
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory _factory;

    public YourClass(IDbContextFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public YourAdminMethod()
    {
        using (var context = _factory.CreateAdminContext())
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }

    public YourAppMethod()
    {
        using (var context = _factory.CreateAppContext())
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

and then you just need one binding in your Ninject bindings for IDbContextFactory, which can be singleton.

```
kernel.Bind<IDbContextFactory>().To<DbContextFactory>().InSingletonScope();
```